# Is there a way to find out which container miss the specific metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kube-state-metrics

I'm trying to find all containers that does not have any resources spec in the cluster and make an alert for that.
Now I'm thinking about use all `container` and `pod` label in `kube_pod_container_info` query and do an `absent` query for `kube_pod_container_resource_requests`,but dont know how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to meet my demand: `container_memory_working_set_bytes{id=~".*besteffort.*",container!="POD",pod!=""}` all containers under this condition can be treated as "containers that does not have any resources spec"

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [unless](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) operator:

> `vector1` unless `vector2` results in a vector consisting of the elements of `vector1` for which there are no elements in `vector2` with exactly matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

In the context of this question, you can take for example `container_cpu_system_seconds_total`, which seems to be for any container, and `container_spec_cpu_quota` which appears for the containers with a CPU limit set. So to show which containers have no CPU limit:

```
container_cpu_system_seconds_total{container!="POD",container=~".+"} 
unless on (pod, container) container_spec_cpu_quota
```

Finding which containers have no memory limit requires a different approach. If a container has no memory limit, its `container_spec_memory_limit_bytes` metric is set to `0`. That is, the metric is always present and `unless` won't help in this case, but `and` will:

```
# the top line is the same as before
container_cpu_system_seconds_total{container!="POD",container=~".+"}
and on (pod, container) container_spec_memory_limit_bytes == 0
```

Comment: It also works for me, and i just want to find all containers that do not have any `requests` and dont care about `limits`, and the metric `kube_pod_container_resource_requests` have both cpu and memroy spec, so it is simple: `kube_pod_container_status_running == 1 unless on (namespace,pod,container)(kube_pod_container_resource_requests)`